# Cookiecutter Template Dependency Management

Tags: python, templates, jinja2, dependency-management, cookiecutter

I'm developing a cookiecutter template. My template has some dependencies. For example, in `hooks/post_gen_project.py` I want to show a message using `rich.print`. How can I satisfy such a requirement?

Also, I've seen many cookiecutter templates with either `setup.py`, `pyproject.toml`, or `setup.cfg` files included in their root directory. What is the point of that?! At first, I thought that might be a way to add dependencies to my template but that didn't work and wondering about the whole idea behind that. *Unfortunately, cookiecutter has a weak documentation describing all these concepts and details!*

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

##### Solution 1

A practice would be installing the dependencies within the `pre_gen_project.py` hook file.

```py
try:
    import rich
except ModuleNotFoundError:
    import subprocess

    subprocess.run(
        [
            "pip",
            "install",
            "--disable-pip-version-check",
            "--no-python-version-warning",
            "-q",
            "rich",
        ]
    )
```

This way, right before when `post_gen_project` gets triggered, it installs `rich` so that you can use `rich.print` in `post_gen_project.py` with no issues.

##### Solution 2

Another solution would be to keep a `cc_requirements.txt` file within your `{{cookiecutter.project_slug}}/` (or wherever you keep the template files) and put all your dependencies there.

```
rich==<desired-version>
```

Then, in `post_gen_project.py` file, use the following instruction to..

- firstly, install the dependencies.
- secondly, remove the `cc_requirements.txt` file.

Here would be the content of `post_gen_project.py` file.

```py
import os

# ...

PROJECT_DIRECTORY = os.path.realpath(os.path.curdir)

def remove_file(filepath: str) -> None:
    """removes a file

    Args:
        filepath (str): path to file
    """
    os.remove(os.path.join(PROJECT_DIRECTORY, filepath))


def install_requirements():
    requirements_file = os.path.join(PROJECT_DIRECTORY, "cc_requirements.txt")
    subprocess.check_call(
        [
            "pip",
            "install",
            "--disable-pip-version-check",
            "--no-python-version-warning",
            "-qUr",
            requirements_file,
        ]
    )
    remove_file(requirements_file)

# ...

if __name__ == "__main__":
    ...
    install_requirements()
    import rich
    # ...
```

##### `setup.py`, `setup.cfg`, `pyproject.toml`

These files are often there for the sake of managing the metadata corresponding to the template. Some specific metadata keywords are just needed from those files such as `version` and not all of them. For instance, if you look around the `packages` keyword in those files, they are empty most of the time meaning when someone tries installing them, ultimately, nothing (functional) actually gets shipped!